# Prevent active file removal on an NFS filesystem

Tags: shell, nfs, rm, open-files

I clear my logs using following script -

```
find "." -mtime 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

But it deletes the active files also and creates `.nfs…` files instead. Is there any way to prevent deletion of active files?

Comment: How do you define "active file"? Also removing a file does not create any other files. You have some external force in play here.

Comment: If any other process is using it ..deleting it creates .nfs files.

Comment: @Patrick The `.nfs…` files are created by the NFS server when a file is deleted while open on an NFS client.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**
**Use this Simple Bash Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
check_in="/your/path/"
while IFS= read -r f
do
    fuser "${f}" || echo rm "${f}"
done < <(find ${check_in} -mtime 1 -type f)
```

Note: it will do nothing, it will just print file with rm which will be remove after removing `echo` command

**Method 2 Using xargs**

```
find "." -mtime 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c "fuser {} || echo rm {}"
```

Comment: I do not have fuser .. and when i replaced it with lsof its not deleting old files.

Comment: This would work only if the files are open on the same machine where the deletion is happening, not if the files are open on another NFS client.

Comment: @NoviceUser have you tried with `pgrep -f ${f}` ?

Comment: pgrep: No matching criteria specified